# Eigenvalues of the inverse of $A^TA$ strictly positive.

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

I believe that $A^TA$ is a key matrix structure because of its connection to variance-covariance matrices, which are used in data analysis (e.g. linear regression or principal component analysis). There are interesting properties to $A^TA$, which I think include symmetry and positive semi-definiteness, and real eigenvalues. Just to share my approximate degree of familiarity with the topic.

However, I am missing at least a rung in the ladder when attempting to understand [this answer in CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/197364/67822), which revolves around the expression:

$$X'X = V D V', \quad D = \begin{bmatrix}
d_1  & & \\
&  \ddots & \\ 
& & d_p
\end{bmatrix}, d_i \geq 0$$

In particular I would appreciate being tipped-off as to why the following statement is obvious:

> "Now since matrix inversion corresponds to inversion of the
>   eigenvalues, the OLS estimator requires $(X′X)^{-1}=VD^{−1}V′$ (note
>   that $V′=V^{−1}$). Obviously this only works if all eigenvalues are
>   strictly greater than zero, $d_i>0$."

Comment: Where did you stuck? It is explained in the excerpt you quoted. Notice that $d_i$'s are the eigen values and the inverse of a diagonal matrix is a diagonal matrix with the inverse of the diagonal components.

Comment: the eigenvalues of $X'X$ can't be negative. If one eigenvalue is zero, the matrix isn't invertible. So Computing the inverse makes no sense.

Comment: @user251257 The fact that a zero eigenvalue makes the matrix singular is true of all square matrices?

Comment: yes. Just compare the definitions of singular and eigenvalues. It is straight forward.

Comment: @AntoniParellada A good way of remembering that fact is that the determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be some Linear algebra facts/results will make it clearer. From the equality $X'X = VDV'$, where $V$ is orthogonal matrix, hence $V'=V^{-1}$, you deduce that $X'X$ is similar to $D=diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_2)$. As such, they have the same eigenvalues. So, because the OLS estimator is defined by $(X'X)^{-1}X'y$, you need to invert the $(X'X)$ and moreover its inverse have to be positive definite matrix in order to minimize the square errors. This stems from the fact that $(X'X)^{-1}$ is the Hessian matrix of the $S(\beta)=(y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta)$.  Thus, for $(X'X)$ to be invertible it has to be full-ranked matrix, namely all eigenvalues have to *differ* from $0$, and for the positive definite property it is required that each its eigenvalue will be strictly positive, i.e. $\lambda_i >0$, $\forall i$.